# C# If item is not in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array with these 3 items:

```
string[] departmentArray = {
    "Warranty Service Representative",
    "Warranty Service Administrative Manager",
    "Warranty and Site Administrator"
};
```

and I have this string

```
var department = "Warranty Service Representative"
```

I have this condition that is suppose to test if the string department is not in the `departmentArray`

```
if (Array.Exists(departmentArray, element => element != department)){
}
```

Clearly the string is in the array, so it should return false, but this returns true for my string. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: On top of the answers below, `Any()` may work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wouldn't this be simpler?

```
string[] departmentArray = { 
    "Warranty Service Representative", 
    "Warranty Service Administrative Manager", 
    "Warranty and Site Administrator" };

String department = "Warranty Service Representative";

if (departmentArray.Contains(department) == false)
{
}
```

Comment: What assembly do I need to use Contains?

Comment: I get this error Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and no extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of your program.   (I'm surprised it isn't already there, it is a Linq Extension).

Comment: The <string> after Contains could also be excluded, as the compiler can derive what it should be.

Comment: What about something for a Dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 12):

```
if (!Array.Exists(departmentArray, element => element == department))
{
}
```

In this case, underlying logic looks like:

```
!(departmentArray[0] == department || departmentArray[1] == department || ..)
```

While in your code, you have:

```
departmentArray[0] != department || departmentArray[1] != department || ..
```

Comment: This will not work because in some cases I will have an array with 1 item and the string will match the one item in the array and will return true when I want that to return false

Comment: @user979331 Are you sure it will not work?   Did you try it?

Comment: You might be confused by the expanded logic in the second part of my answer. Just try `if (!Array.Exists(departmentArray, element => element == department))` instead of `if (Array.Exists(departmentArray, element => element != department))`

Comment: To try to explain it in "human speak," your code is saying "If any of the elements of the array do not equal the department..."  This answer is looking for an element equal to department.  The expression will return true if any are equal, or false if none are.  By moving the ! to the beginning, it's saying "If none of the elements equal department," which is your expected result.

Answer (score 2):

the code:

```
if (Array.Exists(departmentArray, element => element != department))
{
}
```

is `true` if exists any element in `departmentArray` `!=` of `department`, that is why in this case the result is `true` instead of `false` (obviously there is strings in `departmentArray` different to `department`). So, if you want to check if `department` isn't in `departmentArray` try something like this:

```
bool IsNotInArray(String[] array, string element){
    return !Array.Exists(array, e => e == element);
}
```