# if statement seems to not be working with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if I'm overloading anything but when I add all the conditions I need to one if statement it always returns true. It seems to always show my error message, but when I only add one condition it works perfectly fine. Also, I know my code is messy I'm just a novice, go easy on me.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
string[] Class = new string[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ", "KK", "LL", "MM", "NN", "OO" };
double[] Rate = new double[] { .015, .023, .010, .042, .051, .004, .022, .030, .001, .010, .020, .030, .045, .033, .050 };
Console.Write("Please enter vehicle classification: ");
string Vclass = Console.ReadLine();
if (Vclass != "AA" || Vclass != "BB" || Vclass != "CC" || Vclass != "DD" || Vclass != "EE" || Vclass != "FF" || Vclass != "GG" || Vclass != "HH" || Vclass != "II" || Vclass != "JJ" || Vclass != "KK" || Vclass != "LL" || Vclass != "MM" || Vclass != "NN" || Vclass != "OO")
{
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("There is an error with the vehicle class.");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
}
```

Comment: `||` is the `OR` operator. If you type `AA` then `AA != BB` which enters the `if` statement.

Comment: `Vclass != "AA" || Vclass != "BB"` is always true, you need to use `&&` (or `! Class.Contains(Vclass)`).

Comment: The value will always *not be* at least one of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the OR operator in an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158580/what-is-the-or-operator-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: I assume you want something like `if (!Class.Contains(VClass)) { ... }` although this would be case sensitive

Comment: Also it would be much simpler to write _"if (!Class.Contains(VClass))"_ to check if VClass is in your Class array. As @Equalsk beat me to it - then use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as the second parameter to the Conatins method if you want it to be a case insensitive search

Comment: @Equalsk : then why not  { if (!Class.Contains(VClass.ToUpper())).{..} }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# If item is not in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023031/c-sharp-if-item-is-not-in-array)

Comment: @Rob It depends on if OP wants it to assume uppercase or not I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I've got a bowl of fruits. I want to make sure there are no fruits in it that I dont like. The fruits I like are: *apples*, *bananas*, *grapes* and *kiwis*.

So the ones I don't like are those that are not *apples* **AND** are not *bananas* **AND** are not *grapes* **AND** are not a *kiwis*.

The ones I don't like are most definitely not the ones that arent *apples* **OR**  *bananas* **OR** *grapes* **OR** *kiwis*.

`||` is the equivalent of a lazy **OR**. Your condition should be using a lazy **AND**: `&&`.

```
if (Vclass != "AA" && 
    Vclass != "BB" && 
    Vclass != "CC" && 
    Vclass != "DD" && /*..etc*/)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is one of those "now I feel stupid moments".

Comment: @MatthewFinateri Oh, we all have plenty of those, don't sweat it ;)

Comment: @MatthewFinateri: happens to us all at times with complex if statements. Another approach would be to list all valid conditions & then negate it - _if (! (VClass=="AA" || VClass=="BB" .... ))_

Answer (score -1):

So, basically, you're looking for this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
string[] Class = new string[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ", "KK", "LL", "MM", "NN", "OO" };
double[] Rate = new double[] { .015, .023, .010, .042, .051, .004, .022, .030, .001, .010, .020, .030, .045, .033, .050 };
Console.Write("Please enter vehicle classification: ");
string Vclass = Console.ReadLine();
if (!Class.Contains(Vclass))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("There is an error with the vehicle class.");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
}
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the question that OP is trying to ensure the entered text is contained within the `Class` array so it's your second example.

Comment: That is what the OP wants - but the answer does not explain why his  if statement is not working - it is more important to answer the question in this case.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. However, I don't answer people's questions to get downvotes.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you arguably didn't answer anything. A short explanation of _why_ this solves the problem would be desirable.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, ill keep .contains in mind for the future.

Comment: As @Equalsk & I commented - probably the downvote is because you didn't answer the question. Only fixed the problem - so in future you have not helped OP if he has a similar issue that cannot be fixed by your solution to this problem

Comment: @PaulF Without a code example, he will not have understood your point. It takes your explanation _and_ an example to be able to grok the concept.

Comment: `It takes your explanation and an example to be able to grok the concept.` - You're missing one of those in your answer.

Comment: @Aaron: just responding to your comment about _"not answering to get downvotes"_ so that in future you can avoid the downvotes if that is your concern.